# java.rmi.ServerError: Error occurred in server thread; nested exception is:

Tags: rmi, rmiregistry

I'm upgrading jdk from 8 to 10 and get an exception:

```
    java.rmi.ServerError: Error occurred in server thread; nested exception is:
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/Timestamp at     java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:388)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
```

The rmiregistry can be started correctly, but my RMI server program can't bind my object. Why?

Comment: Your question doesn't have enough details. Try to explain what exactly you were trying to do when you got this error message. And also include code snippets if possible.

Comment: My Remote Interface
package excelhk.objbus;

import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface testRMI extends Remote {
 String sayHello(java.sql.Timestamp aTime) throws RemoteException;
}

Comment: /*Remote Interface*/
public interface testRMI extends Remote {
 String sayHello(Timestamp aTime)...;
}

/*Server Class*/
public class testRMISrv implements testRMI {
 public String sayHello(Timestamp aTime).{
        return "Hello, world!";
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
         ....
            registry.bind("Hello", stub);
    }
}

/*Start Rmiregistry*/
start rmiregistry -J-classpath -J$CLASSPATH

/*Run Server Class*/
java -cp apath excelhk.objbus.testRMISrv

Noted 
If use java.util.Date for the method sayHello(), it works fine!

Comment: There is something seriously wrong with your Java installation if it can't find `java,sql.Timestamp`.

Comment: were you able to figure out a solution? I am having the same problem with Java 11